# Delegate set in switch can't be used outside of switch

Tags: c#

Can somebody tell me why this doesn't work? I'm learning C# and cannot figure out why I can't use my `process` delegate in the final `WriteLine`.  The error that it gives me is

```
Use of unassigned local variable 'process'
```

I moved it into the `do while` and it still gives me the same error. Why won't the set process work outside the switch?

```cs
class Program
    {
        delegate double ProcessDelegate(double arg1, double arg2);

        static double Sum(double arg1, double arg2) => arg1 + arg2;
        static double Difference(double arg1, double arg2) => arg1 - arg2;
        static double Average(double arg1, double arg2) => (arg1 + arg2) / 2;
        static double Product(double arg1, double arg2) => arg1 * arg2;
        static double Dividend(double arg1, double arg2) => arg1 / arg2;
        static double Modulus(double arg1, double arg2) => arg1 % arg2;
        static double GetDouble(string displayText, string errorMessage)
        {
            double input;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(displayText);
                try
                {
                    input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    break;
                }
                catch (System.FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                }
            }

            return input;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] availableFunctions = { "1) Sum", "2) Difference", "3) Average", "4) Product", "5) Dividend", "6) Modulus" };
            ProcessDelegate process;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter two numbers to perform a function on them!");
            double arg1 = GetDouble("Enter a number:", "That's not a number");
            double arg2 = GetDouble("Enter a number:", "That's not a number");
            double desiredFunction;

            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do with those to numbers?");
            foreach (string f in availableFunctions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);
            };

            bool complete = false;
            do
            {

                desiredFunction = GetDouble("Please choose a number between 1 and 6.", "That is not a number.");

                switch (desiredFunction)
                {
                    case 1:
                        process = new ProcessDelegate(Sum);
                        complete = true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        process = new ProcessDelegate(Difference);
                        complete = true;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        process = new ProcessDelegate(Average);
                        complete = true;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        process = new ProcessDelegate(Product);
                        complete = true;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        process = new ProcessDelegate(Dividend);
                        complete = true;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        process = new ProcessDelegate(Modulus);
                        complete = true;
                        break;
                }

            } while (complete == false);

            Console.WriteLine($"Result: {process(arg1, arg2)}");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Either add a `default:` case or initialize `process` with a default value before the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is displeased because there might be a case that isn't accounted for in your switch case in  which case process will not be initialized. So either add this to your switch:

```
default:
    process = null;
    break;
```

Or initialize process to be null at the beginning:

```
ProcessDelegate process = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation

[Compiler Error CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165)

> The C# compiler doesn't allow the use of uninitialized variables. If
>   the compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been
>   initialized, it generates compiler error CS0165. For more information,
>   see [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). This error is generated when the compiler encounters a
>   construct that might result in the use of an unassigned variable, even
>   if your particular code does not. This avoids the necessity of overly
>   complex rules for definite assignment.

To fix this, you can assign `null` when you declare it, or in all branches it isnt being set.

This tells the compiler explicitly you can expect `null` in certain situations, in turn allowing static analysis to pass

Answer (score 0):

In your case you do ensure that that the `process` variable will always contain `not null`. Anyhow the compiler doesn't know that. Why you might ask; The compiler can be stupid sometimes and it simple doesn't see, that it will never be `null`.

However you can make a workaround for it. You can either set the default value of `process` to `null` right when you declare `process`.

```cs
ProcessDelegate process = null;
```

---

Or by adding a default statement to your `switch`.

```cs
switch (desiredFunction)
{
    // Other cases
    case 6:
        process = new ProcessDelegate(Modulus);
        complete = true;
        break;
    default:
        process = null;
        break;
}
```

---

Also you could save yourself from the required `complete` bool, by using the first solution mentioned above and checking if the `process` is equal to `null` in the `while` statement.

```cs
ProcessDelegate process = null;
// ...
do
{

    desiredFunction = GetDouble("Please choose a number between 1 and 6.", "That is not a number.");

    switch (desiredFunction)
    {
        // Other cases
        case 1:
            process = new ProcessDelegate(Modulus);
            break;
    }

} while (process == null);
```